# Connect a GMAC to another GMAC

Tags: switches, phy, mac

I am looking into the KSZ9893 3-port switch. It has two(2) ports 10/100/1000 PHY. And one(1) GMAC with RGMII/RMII/MII interface. When I check the schematic of the SAMA5D3 Evaluation board they connect this GMAC interface(KSZ9893) directly into the GMAC of the SAMA5D3. Is this doable?
[image: SAMA5D3 evaluation board]

I would like to connect the SAMe70 GMAC interface to the KSZ9893. Can I use the RMII interface to connect the SAMe70 to the KSZ9893 GMAC?
[image: SAMe70 GMAC part]
SAMe70 block diagram

[image: KSZ9893 block block diagram]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503466/can-two-ethernet-mac-chips-be-connected-directly-without-going-thru-phy but you need to use GMII or RGMII for gigabit speeds. RMII is for 10/100 ethernet.

Comment: In this case SAMe70 only has MIi/RMII. But the KSZ9893 has an RMII interface and a Switch-engine. So it should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. The MII stuff needs to be changed a bit but otherwise there’s no reason you can’t make a direct MAC to MAC connection.

Answer (score 0):

The port 3 of the KSZ9893 can be configured as PHY mode. This is described on page 55, for the MII mode, of the datasheet and the pins of configuration are listed on the "Configuration strap" section.